# Dynamic programming function in O(nk) time

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given two integer arrays A of size n and B of size k, and knowing that all items
in the array B are unique, I want to find an algorithm that finds indices j' < j'', such
that all elements of B belong to A[j' : j''] and value |j''-j'|is minimized or
returns zero if there are no such indices at all. I also note that A can contain duplicates.

To provide more clarity, we can consider array A = {1, 2, 9, 6, 7, 8, 1, 0, 0, 6} and B {1, 8, 6}, then you can see that B ⊆ A[1 : 6] and B ⊆ A[4 : 7], but at the same time 7−4 < 6−1,
thus algorithm should output j'= 4 and j''= 7.

I want to find an algorithm that runs in O(nk) time.

My work so far is that I was thinking for each j'∈ [n], I can compute the minimum j'' ≥ j' so that B ⊆ A[j', j'']. If I assume B = {b1, ..., bk}, let Next[j'][i] denote the smallest index t ≥ j' so that at = b_i, i.e., the index of next element after a_j' (included) which equals bi.
In particular if such t doesn’t exist, simply let Next[j'][i] = ∞. If I am able to show that the minimum j'' is the following

j'' = max i∈[k] of Next[j'][i],

then I think I will be able to design a dynamic programming algorithm to compute Next in O(nk) time. Any help on this dynamic programming problem would be much appreciated!

Comment: Hi @fabiocontreras
Sorry if I missed anything, by reading the description of the problem I think that the values themselves don't matter.
You could have been looking for any set of symbols or any set of whatever.
If that's the case you should be rather looking for an algoritm where the complexity is just based on the number of items (n) and not their values (k being often assumed as the sum of their values).
In the present case, if you iterate by considering all adjacent subsets of 1 item at iteration first, 2 items at iter 2, and so on, you should be able to find a recursion in O(n^2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run a sliding window that maintains the invariant of including all elements of B. That's O(n) with a hashmap.

Comment: To break it down for the OP a bit: Maintain a hashtable f[] of frequencies, so that for all i ∈ B, f[i] is the number of copies of i in the current window. Initially, start with a window of [0 .. 0] and extend the right edge of it rightward until all entries of f[] are nonzero, at, say, R. Now contract the left edge rightward until some f[i] becomes 0, let's say with the left edge at L: [L-1, R] is the optimal solution *that begins at L-1*, and dominates all solutions [j, R] with j < L-1. Repeat this right-extend-left-contract process to find dominating solutions beginning to the right of L-1.